# iOS app crashes whenever view is added

Tags: ios, facebook, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using Facebook Authentication with the Parse Framework. If the user login is successful I run this code

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loginfbsucc) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Then inside of:

```
- (void)loginfbsucc{
    [self.view addSubview:mainscreen];
}
```

I attempt to add that subview. Whenever I add that specific subview the app crashes, but if the view name is different it doesnt. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Do you have a crash log?  Is `mainscreen` allocated by the time you call that function?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in that method, can you verify that `mainscreen` has not been dealloc'd?

Comment: @oltman I set a breakpoint, I dont see any errors in the log, but In purple the line is highlighted and it says "exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x8)"

Comment: @DanF no crash log it just says (lldb)

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize `mainscreen`?

Comment: @oltman how would I deallocate the mainscreen view when it is removed from the superview?

Comment: @BlackRider thats all the code I have do I have to initialize the view in some other way?

Comment: That sounds like it's being autoreleased. If you are using ARC and don't have a reference to `mainscreen`, it will be released when it is no longer strongly referenced. What you probably want is to turn `mainscreen` into a property with the `strong` attribute. That way, as long as you have a reference to `mainscreen` (i.e., don't set `self.mainscreen` to nil), it will be retained.

Comment: @oltman I added this code to my .h file `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *mainscreen;` but now nothing happens when I attempt to add the view (but the app does not crash).

Comment: Are you referencing it as `self.mainscreen` instead of just `mainscreen`?

Comment: @oltman now the app crashes with the same `(lldb)` error

Comment: Are you also assigning to `self.mainscreen`? It sounds like you should probably read up a bit on Objective C properties https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Comment: @oltman I dont think it has anything to do with the way the view is defined of called. Using Parse Facebook authentication kind of messes up the whole app. Are you familiar with [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers)?

Comment: I am not, but it really does sound like it has to do with how you're retaining `mainscreen`. A bad access error occurs when you try to access memory that your program doesn't own, which is what happens when you have a pointer to released memory. Simply using a pointer to an object won't retain it, which is why you need to use a strong property.